# Use a lambda to upload an S3 object to external api

Tags: api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I have an external api that i need to upload some s3 objects to and i'd like to do it using a lambda. Is it possible to do this without running into size limits in a lambda?

I've tried to find what those size limits are but also haven't had any luck. Saw something that said 512MB but wasn't sure if that was accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

512MB is the limit of `/tmp` directory storage. This shouldn't be an issue, because recently lambda supports [integration with EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) which essentially has more storage than you probably needed.